# Azure Pipeline Releases - Download list of work items

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Has anyone downloaded a list of work items linked to a Azure DevOps ***Release*** ?

If so, what methods are possible: PowerBI, API call, project query ?

REf: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Answer (score 0):

We can find this API easily by searching at the network traffic in the F12 tools in the browser.

API:

```
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org name} /{project name} /_apis/Release/releases/{release id}/workitems?baseReleaseId={release id}&artifactAlias={name}
```

[image]

In addition, we found this Blog: [How to retrieve all work items associated with a release pipeline using Azure DevOps API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/how-to-retrieve-all-work-items-associated-with-a-release-pipeline-using-azure-devops-api/), we can see how to list these work items via client API.